# How do you install/download a specific version of the cassandra distributed database in mac os x?

Tags: macos, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I was trying to install Cassandra 2.0.5 for my Mac OS X (mavericks) but whenever I googled install Cassandra 2.0.5 I can't seem to find how to install the specific version of Cassandra that I want to install.

Is there a way to install a specific version of cassandra in general? Maybe through brew or something like that? Or whatever, I just want to install Cassandra 2.0.5 (but a more general procedure might be more useful in the long term).

Comment: Do you not want to use the tar install?

Comment: https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; You can get em [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/).

But.. there's a fun way too using git:

```
// -b cassandra-2.0 because you want a 2.0.x version of C*
// if you want a 2.1.x version use -b cassandra-2.1 and so on for other branches
git clone -b cassandra-2.0 git://git.apache.org/cassandra.git
cd cassandra
git tag -l
```

You'll now get a long list of different verions, here is a short segment of said list:

```
cassandra-2.0.0-beta2
cassandra-2.0.0-rc1
cassandra-2.0.0-rc2
cassandra-2.0.1
cassandra-2.0.2
cassandra-2.0.3
cassandra-2.0.4
cassandra-2.0.5
```

Next you can checkout the tag:

```
git checkout tags/cassandra-2.0.5
```

Finally you build C* using `ant build` and you're all set to `./bin/cassandra -f`